# Java project does not compile with error "package X does not exist"

Tags: java, exception, package

When using VSCode we have 0 errors and our only warnings are "x is never used" (either because it's unfinished portions or because we put redundant imports).

But when we try to compile classes, we get several errors saying **symbols or packages aren't found or do not exist**. (see below)

I think the main issues are "`package storage does not exist`" and "`package vehicle does not exist`". After solving those, I think everything should click back into place.

I'm sure it's something dumb like syntax or folder placement but we could not solve it.

The two suggestions I got until the former post got deleted were :

<< Make the "private ControlCenter" part of the code public >>

As long as the class itself is public I don't think the problem comes from there. We're using the "singleton" design pattern for ControlCenter, so its has a private constructor because we're using the Singleton design for it.

​

<< Pay attention to uppercase vs lowercase >>

I renamed every package that used PascalCase into all-lowercase, and every class has its name in PascalCase. But even after that the problems subsist.

- **FULL ERROR TRACE**

Here's the trace of the errors (after the modifications mentionned above, it was roughly the same before) :

```
javac src/main/*.java -d classes
src\main\ControlCenter.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    protected List<Station> allStations;
                  ^
  symbol:   class Station
  location: class ControlCenter
src\main\ControlCenter.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    private ControlCenter(ArrayList<Station>allStations){
                                    ^
  symbol:   class Station
  location: class ControlCenter
src\main\ControlCenter.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    public void addStation(Station station){
                          ^
  symbol:   class Station
  location: class ControlCenter
src\main\ControlCenter.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
    protected void moveBikes(Station stationGivingBikes, Station stationGettingBikes){
                              ^
  symbol:   class Station
  location: class ControlCenter
src\main\ControlCenter.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
    protected void moveBikes(Station stationGivingBikes, Station stationGettingBikes){
                                                          ^
  symbol:   class Station
  location: class ControlCenter
src\main\ControlCenter.java:4: error: package storage does not exist
import storage.*;
^
src\main\ControlCenter.java:5: error: package storage.temporarystorage does not exist
import storage.temporarystorage.*;
^
src\main\ControlCenter.java:6: error: package vehicle does not exist
import vehicle.*;
^
src\main\ControlCenter.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
            uniqueInstance = new ControlCenter(new ArrayList<Station>());
                                                            ^
  symbol:   class Station
  location: class ControlCenter
9 errors
```

- **What our directory looks like :**

[link to image](https://imgur.com/a/Sbb4XUc)

And the code of some of the problematic classes :

​

**ControlCenter**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import storage.*; import storage.temporarystorage.*; import vehicle.\*;

public class ControlCenter { /\*\* \* exhaustive list of every station \*/ 
protected List<Station> allStations; 
protected static final int TIMEINTERVALBEFOREREDISTRIBUTION = 2;
private static ControlCenter uniqueInstance;

private ControlCenter(ArrayList<Station>allStations){
    this.allStations = new ArrayList<>();
}

/**
 * @return a unique instance of this controlStation class
 */

public static ControlCenter getInstance(){

    if(uniqueInstance == null){
        uniqueInstance = new ControlCenter(new ArrayList<Station>());
    }

    return uniqueInstance;
}

    [other methods ...]

}
```

**TemporaryStorage**

```
package storage.temporarystorage;

import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;

import storage.Storage;

import vehicle.\*;

public class Station extends TemporaryStorage {

public Station (int id, int capacity, ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleList){

    super(id, capacity,vehicleList);
    }

}
```

If you need any more info let me know.

I expect insight to modify my code to make it compile, or at least reduce the number of errors.

Answer (score 1):

> `javac src/main/*.java -d classes`

This asks your OS to enumerate every file that matches the `*.java` glob in the `src/main` directory. So, this **does not include, for example, `src/main/temporarystorage/Station.java`**. Because that's not how your OS globber works, and there is no simple way to say; "List every file ending in java in this dir *and every subdir of this dir*".

Thus, no wonder it can't find Station.java. How could it?

### Solution 1: List em

```bash
javac src/main/*.java src/main/temporarystorage/*.java ––– -d classes
```

Will work, if you add each and every subdir at the long dash. Yes, every time you add a package you'll have to remember to add it to this `javac` command, at which point you might be thinking about making a shell script, or even using `find` or `dir /s` or similar shenanigans to automate the process.

Congratulations!!! You're writing a build system! However, some pretty good ones exist, don't reinvent stuff unneccessarily:

### Solution 2: Use a build system

This is where 99% of all non-academic java projects end up. You use for example [Maven](https://maven.apache.org), which does know that every java source file in every subdir all needs to be compiled. You'll have to read the tutorial. A ton of em exist, it's a fairly popular build system. There are many alternatives if you don't like it. For example, gradle. Or ant.

### Solution 3: `-sourcepath` hackery

You can attempt this:

```bash
javac -sourcepath src/main -d classes src/main/*.java
```

This has some downsides. In particular, this doesn't actually compile stuff unless it is needed, which sounds great, but you end up with lots of new 'main roots' in real apps (plugin architecture, logback endpoints, HTML handle endpoints, the list is long), so that's generally not good (that command will not compile *every java file in this dir and every subdir*, it merely compiles the java files in this dir, but if it compiling it needs some other java file to be compiled, it'll be found and compiled).

I don't recommend this long term.

### So what should I do?

Solution 2. Use a build system. At least, ASAP. For this academic project you might just want to scoot by with the `-sourcepath` hack and if that doesn't work, explicit listing. But, know that no 'real' (actual euros or eyeballs interested in) java project does that.